# Background Notifications in iOS with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I am new to react native and am trying to create an app that allows user to listen to podcast that will be posted weekly via a database. Each time that a new podcast has been posted I would like the user to receive a background notification.

I have done some research and have been able to react local notifications that display whenever the app is opened (as shown below) I have been following this tutorial

https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/localNotifications

[image: Notiifications]

Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Notifications} from 'react-native-notifications';

import HomeStack from './app/nav';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications();

    Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground((notification: Notification, completion) => {
      console.log(`Notification received in foreground: ${notification.title} : ${notification.body}`);
      completion({alert: true, sound: false, badge: true});
    });

    Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened((notification: Notification, completion) => {
      console.log(`Notification opened: ${notification.payload}`);
      completion();
    });
  }
  someLocalNotification = Notifications.postLocalNotification({
  body: 'Local notification!',
  title: 'Local Notification!',
  //sound: "chime.aiff",
  category: 'SOME_CATEGORY',
  userInfo: {},
});

render() {
return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}><HomeStack /></View>
}
}
```

After doing some research I have found some tutorials to be a bit confusing or do not work. I was wondering what is the best way to create background notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate firebase in your project,I am also faced that issue,firebase integration is the solution, to get dynamic notification content when the app is opened or closed.`npm i react-native-firebase`

Comment: Are there any tutorials to set this up?

Comment: Go to react native firebase documentation, both Android and ios integration is available